# Error messages are not displayed using jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I have the following jQuery script.

```
function updateItem(form) {
    var validator = $("#add-experience-form").validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            eventTitle: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            eventTitle: {
                required: "Please, enter a title."
            }
        }
    });

    if (!validator.valid()) {
        return;
    }
```

}

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="/User/AddExperience" id="add-experience-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">                    
    <p>
        <label>Experience Title<span class="required">*</span></label>                    
        <input id="eventTitle" name="eventTitle" required="required" style="width: 350px;" type="text" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="eventTitle" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <br>                 
        <label>&nbsp;</label><span class="tip">50 character maximum</span>                          
    </p>
```

{

Experience Title
                        
                        
                        

                        *@**@
                         50 character maximum

For some reason error message doesn't display for the above form even though validator.valid() evaluates to false.

If it helps, I put this form inside jQuery UI dialog, but I don't think it really matters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -3):

To validate html forms , the simplest way is to combine two open source powerful frameworks twitter bootstrap ( to get nice form ) and jquery.validate.js plugin ( for validation ).

Bootstrap framework : http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ .

Jquery validation plugin : http://jqueryvalidation.org/

So your html code and your script may appear like this

Html code :
First add this link

```
<link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Then

```
<form  method="post" action="/User/AddExperience" id="add-experience-form" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

        <h4 class="text-primary">fields required * </h4>

       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="experienceTitle">Experience Title<span class="req">*</span></label> 
            <div class="col-xs-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventTitle" name="eventTitle">
              <span class="help-block"></span>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>

 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                   <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="newsubmit" id="newsubmit" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
                   </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>


</form>
```

Jquery script : put it in a js file called validate.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
});     

$('#add-experience-form').validate({
    rules: {
        eventTitle: {
            minlength: 2,
            lettersonly:true,
            required: true
        }
    },

    messages: {

        eventTitle: {
            required:"blablabla",
            minlenght:"blablabla",
            maxlenght:"50 character maximum",
            lettersonly: "Letters only please"
        }
    },


    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    },
    success: function (label) {
        $(label).closest('form').find('.valid').removeClass("invalid");
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        element.closest('.control-group').find('.help-block').html(error.text());
    }
}).cancelSubmit=true; // to block the submit of this plugin and call submit to php file
```

});

You can put all these scripts in one folder called js then add them in your code

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/validate.js"></script>
```

For more details you can refer to the documentation http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/